# i want that when i pass the mouse Over a Li, the result shows in the div

Tags: jquery

I want that when i pass the mouse Over a Li, the result shows in the div.

```
<li ><a href="#estaEm">Pai 1</a>
  <ul>
    <li ><a href="#estaEm" >Filho 1</a></li>
    <li ><a href="#estaEm" >Filho 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li ><a href="#estaEm">Pai 2</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#estaEm" >Filho 1</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
</div>
<div id="estaEm" value ="">resultado </div>
```

The jQuery that i did doesnt work in the case only to Father 2:

```
$( "li" ).bind( "mouseover", function() {
    var result=''

    $( this ).find("a").each(function () {
        result += " > " + $( this ).text()
    });

    $("#estaEm").text(result)
});
```

setting the mouse over Son 2: example father 1 > son 2

Comment: First of all, `bind` is now deprecated. Use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead

Comment: Consider adding a jsfiddle. It would make it easier for the members to assist you.

Comment: Your code technically works: [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/k5gucra6/). What exactly do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you need to display the current element link and its parents links (if applicable).

 So I came up with the following code:

```js
var findLinkText = function(ele) {
   return $(ele).find('a:first').text();
}

$("li").on("mouseover", function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation(); // for embeded <li> event
  var result = [];
  //  Find this element link
  var text = findLinkText(this);
  if (text) result.push(text);

  $(this).parents("li").each(function() {
    var txt = findLinkText(this);
    if (txt) result.unshift(txt);
  });

  $("#estaEm").text(result.join(' > '));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <li><a href="#estaEm">Pai 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#estaEm">Filho 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#estaEm">Filho 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#estaEm">Pai 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#estaEm">Filho 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</div>
<div id="estaEm" value="">resultado </div>
```

Comment: Glad I could help - it was a bit tricky to list them in correct order.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've already solved this but if you're interested in another way to do it you can take a look at this:

```
$("li").on('mouseover', function() {
    $("#estaEm").text(GetAnchorTextFromCurrentElement.call(this));
});

function GetAnchorTextFromCurrentElement() {
    return $(this).find('a').map(function(){
        return $(this).text();
    }).get().join(" > ");
}
```

The `map` function takes each item in the array and creates a new array of the same length with the return value you specify in the function you pass the `map` function. Technically you need to call the `get` function to get access the array since this particular version of `map` returns a JQuery Object, but I digress.

Once you have the array you just join each item of the array with the string you want and you get your final result to display in your div.

Since we use the `this` keyword inside of the `GetAnchorTextFromCurrentElement` function, we have to execute the function using the `call` method. If we didn't use the `call` function and tried to access the `this` keyword inside of the function you executed you would get an error of `undefined` because you would be referencing the `GetAnchorTextFromCurrentElement`'s context instead of the on mouseover function's context.

Comment: **Note**: In HTML you're not supposed to have a list item (`li`) outside of either a `ul` or `ol` element. This being said, your code still works because the browser is gracefully handling that for you. However, not all browsers will be so nice.